codes lost after git merge
The situation is like this：
A branch called master, another branch called dev, last branch called feature.
On April 20th，person A pushed a commit m1 to feature.
On April 26th, branch dev is create from branch master,
On April 30th, another person B pushed a commit m2 to master,
On May 5th, person A used cherry-pick to merge m1 from feature to dev,
On May 7th，I merge master to dev， but I find conflict codes(between m1 and m2) is auto merged without info（like unmerged paths),  m2'codes covered m1's.
so I want know why m1 is covered without prompt？
I create another repository try to make a Reproduction, but failed.

How do you mean you found conflicts? If there are conflicts Git won't merge.

m1 and m2 modified the same places，but commit m1 was lost. maybe the whole m1 lost?

*"person A used cherry-pick to merge m1 from feature to dev," - yeah, cherry pick tend to have side effects on conflict handling. thats why cherry pick, reset, and force push should be used sparingly. also, don't do fast forward merge if you want to be able to revert a merge.

Oh，thank you！Perhaps that the reason why code got lost, May I ask what risks may be caused by cherry-pick?

If you used github, you can still roll back and check it manually on the website, the code of the first commits should be there.

Thank you！I know that, but I want to know why the code is lost, perhaps there were any inappropriate actions when submitting the code? If there are any operational errors, I can avoid doing so when submitting the code in the future.
